# R: download of package ‘plyr’ failed

Tags: r, plyr

I am having the next message when trying to install the r package:

```
> install.packages('plyr')
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/plyr_1.8.1.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/plyr_1.8.1.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘plyr’ failed
```

My R version is ‘3.1.3’ and I didn't have the plyr package before.

Ideas of why is it happening?
I haven't seen a solution to my problem in other questions

Comment: I just installed successfully from the same URL, may be just try again

Comment: Not sure why it's trying that URL when the current version is 1.8.2

Comment: (In other words, if you go to http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1 you won't find a link to "plyr_1.8.1.zip", so I'm not sure why that version is the one that is trying to be downloaded.)

Comment: Yes, the page doesn't exist so that 404 error returned. You can directly install it by `install.packages("http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/plyr_1.8.2.zip", repos = NULL)`